# Appropriate Test? Is there a "t-test" for ratios when large number of data points and multiple runs?

Tags: time-series, probability, hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, ratio

N.B. I only have a very basic statistics background since I am in grade 9 in high school. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

My Experiment:

-Part 1: 2 variables (A and B) were each sampled in my homemade wind tunnel simultaneously (1000/s) for 10 seconds=10,000 data points in a run (Run 1) for Configuration 1 at Angle 1
-this was repeated 10 times=10 Runs 
-Next, a ratio (Mean A/Mean B) was calculated from the 2 variables for each run (Configuration 1 Angle 1 Ratios 1-10)

-Part 2: the same procedure as Part 1 was performed for 7 different angles (i.e. Configuration 1, angle 1 for 10 runs, Configuration 1, angle 2 for 10 runs etc in the wind tunnel)

Part 3: The same procedure as Part 1 and Part 2 was conducted for various configurations (Configuration 2, Angles 1-7 each with Runs 1-10, Configuration 3 etc.)

-Now I want  to compare whether these A/B Ratios between a) Configurations (i.e. Configuration 1 Angle 1 vs Configuration 2 Angle 1) and between b) Angles (i.e. Configuration 1 Angle 1 vs. Configuration 1 Angle 2) are "significant" (i.e. different from each other) using some kind of t-test.

I only know t-tests but not sure if I can use them here because of 1) ratios 2) large number of data points. I have SO MUCH data that I'm very confused.

I hope this makes sense. It may seem like a simple problem to you, but if anyone can help I would REALLY appreciate it!